# Clang bug not fixed for more than 5 years. What to do?

Tags: c++, vector, x86, clang, simd

x86 Clang has a bug that I reported back in 2013. It is confirmed, but they have never fixed it. What can I do to make them fix it?

The bug report is here: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17164

Description:

```
__m128  x;  // vector of four float
__m128i y;  // vector of four int
x = y;      // does not convert int to float but preserves the bits
```

The intrinsic vector types such as __m128, __m128i, __m128d are silently bit-cast to each other which gives weird results. All other compilers treat these vector types as different types. There is no option that makes Clang compatible with other compilers for intrinsic vector types.

This is a big problem for the Vector class library ( https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass ). I don't know what to do to make them fix this bug. Please help.

Comment: We need a sad smiley on SO. I've recently found a bug introduced at some point after 5.0.0 (not investigated fully yet) breaking a project. 3 releases are missing it.

Comment: I see how that's problematic for overload resolution, but I don't see why it's surprising that `x = y` copies the bits unchanged if it's going to not error.  That's less surprising than an implicit `_mm_cvtepi32_ps`.  *That* would be super-weird, and be ambiguous for `__m128d` (should it convert 2x double to 2x int64?  Or should it `cvtpd2dq` and leave 2 `int32_t` at the bottom of a vector?)  Normally when I wish I could do `x=y` without cluttering my code with `_mm_castsi128_ps`, it's for using `shufps` or `movhps` on integer data, or `pand` on FP data, or similar.

Comment: I think this would be a better SO question if you include some of the specific cases you need to work around for clang, like the case from that bug you linked.  SO is for programming questions, so are you asking for a technical workaround for clang allowing implicit conversion between different `__m128` types?  I.e. some way to write the class to compile without error, while still allowing users of VCL to freely mix VCL with `_mm_*` intrinsics.  If you're asking how to get clang developers to fix this, that sounds off topic.

Comment: _"What can I do to make them fix it?"_ Submit a pull request? Post on their mailing list and/or contact developers you might know directly? While I see the problem, I'm not sure that this type of question is a good fit for StackOverflow, since we really can't _answer_ it, only make suggestions.

Comment: We can only answer "how can I work around it".

Comment: I'm not sure if implicit conversion would be good here. Mostly because `__m128i` does not necessarily mean `4x int32`, but could also be `4x uint32` or `8x int16`, or whatever. The obvious workaround is to write a wrapper class which overloads the conversion operator.

Comment: If you want to fix the bug you either go ahead and do it (Clang is opensource) or pay someone to do it. That's a business matter, not suitable for SO. If you want to find a workaround, please state it explicitly. You can then use the configure/make machinery (e.g. autoconf, automake) to test for the bug and set/unset a preprocessor symbol accordingly (to select the right implementation).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: detecting compilers with this behaviour is already trivial: `#ifdef __clang__`.  Or in the future, with `#if __clang__ < some_number`.  Agner Fog's VCL is a (pretty nice) header-only library that wraps the `__m128` types, but allows mixing and matching `Vec4f` or `Vec4i` VCL types with Intel intrinsics with stuff like `operator __m128() const` and constructors that take `__m128` or `__m128i`.

Comment: @chtz: VCL *is* a library of wrappers for `__m128`, `__m128i`, etc. but one of the design goals is allowing mix and match with `_mm` Intel intrinsics by having implicit conversion to/from `__m128`.  So you can use VCL types as a drop-in replacement to get nice `v1 + v2` syntax without having to go through VCL wrappers for *every* intrinsic.  So VCL only has to provide functions that overload operators, or that do something not (always) available with a single intrinsic, depending on the target level of SSE/AVX.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't see what the problem is then: https://godbolt.org/z/pCi_DV

Comment: @A-Fog: If you want a workaround, could you clarify (in the question itself) what behavior you are seeking? Do you want implicit conversion or not? Both should be possible with wrapper classes.

Comment: @chtz: In Agner's clang bug report, `Vec4fb` (the FP-boolean wrapper class for `cmpps` results) also has an  `operator Vec4i() const`.  GCC compiles it, clang doesn't:  https://godbolt.org/z/VwvOsy

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, that is one of the reasons I try to avoid conversion operators (unless there is no other way, e.g., when converting to primitive types) and prefer conversion constructors. Another bonus is that constructors can be explicit without requiring C++11.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am not asking for a workaround, I already have one though it is not very good. I am asking who to contact to make them fix the bug. I think it is a problem that Clang is different from all other compilers and different from the official Intel specifications. It is also a problem that they are not fixing a confirmed bug.

Comment: @AFog I don't see any problem with clang if you replace your conversion operators by conversion constructors (you need a few forward declarations for that. See my previously posted https://godbolt.org/z/pCi_DV). If you want to have your issue fixed I can't help, and I don't think this is on-topic here (maybe unless you show specific parts of the compiler code itself).

Comment: @chtz. Yes, conversion operators is a mess, but you can't have a conversion constructor when the target type is an intrinsic type, such as __m128.

Comment: @AFog Yes, but as I said, you can implement every other conversion (i.e., except those to primitive types) via constructors. C++ will always prefer a direct constructor vs having to call both conversion-operator and a constructor (to the best of my knowledge).